# Problem when learning forEach method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I start learning Javascript since a week and I try to do some practice about the loop,
So I try to make a function which each time I call it, I doubled the numbers in an array.

I manage to do it with the classic "for" loop like this as an example:

```
var numbers = [2, 5, 37, 500, 75]; 

function getDoubled() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    (numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2);
  }
}
```

So here the numbers in my array doubled each time I call the function `getDoubled();` and now I try to do the same with `forEach` method.

```
var numbers = [2, 5, 37, 500, 75];

function getDoubled(array) {
  array.forEach(function(number) {
    (number = number * 2);
  })
}
```

But I wasn't able to change the array when I call the function `getDoubled(numbers)`, however if I test with `console.log(number*2)`, it worked in the console, so I wasn't able to figure it out the mistake.

Comment: `console.log(getDoubled(numbers))` but it doesn't return an array you need to `array.push(number)` inside callback and  `let array = []` ouside of function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reassigning an identifier has no side-effects. That is, doing `someVariable = somethingNew` will only result in a discernable change in how your script runs if something else references the `someVariable` which has the new value in it. Here, the `number = number * 2` does nothing because nothing is referencing the doubled `number` variable; reassigning the parameter doesn't do anything to the array.

The way to do this with `forEach` would be to reassign the index in the array, just like in the `for` loop.

```js
var numbers = [2,5,37,500,75];
function getDoubled(array) {
    array.forEach(function(number, i){
        array[i] = number * 2;
    })
}
getDoubled(numbers);
console.log(numbers);
```

Alternatively, a nicer approach would be to construct a new array with the changed values, which can be done with `.map`, which creates a new array by performing a callback on every element of the original array - that way you don't have to look at the (unimportant) indicies to get the output you want.

```js
var numbers = [2,5,37,500,75];
function getDoubled(array) {
    return array.map(num => num * 2);
}
console.log(getDoubled(numbers));
```